# Splash screen api not working on android 12 (API 31, 32)

Tags: android, kotlin, splash-screen, android-12, android-splashscreen

I've seen different posts about this, and also an open issue on google where they say it's not a bug, but intended behaviour instead. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/197906327
Although a lot of people say it's not working as intended.

If you open the app from settings -> apps -> myApp then

```
splashScreen.setOnExitAnimationListener
```

gets called a lot of times, the splash screen is shown without the icon, and then the app gets stuck at a blank screen. The same happens with API 31 but here

```
splashScreen.setOnExitAnimationListener
```

doesn't get called at all and is still stuck on the blank screen.

Is there any fix for this? or hack to make it work?

On all other API's it works but not 31 and 32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Jetpack (androidx) > Core` issue 197906327](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/197906327): "`splashScreen.setOnExitAnimationListener()` not called when using `CustomSplashScreen` in debug mode" does not seem to have any fix, only (imperfect) workarounds.

- Either setting the [windowBackground property](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen#implement) of your theme to a solid color. That will prevent the system from displaying the default splash screen, and your custom splash screen will be displayed instead.
  See also "[Migrate your existing splash screen implementation to Android 12 and higher](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen/migrate)"
- Or using the [`setOnExitAnimationListener()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/window/SplashScreen#setOnExitAnimationListener(android.window.SplashScreen.OnExitAnimationListener)) to listen for when the splash screen is dismissed.

On that last option:

The issue is that the `setOnExitAnimationListener()` method is not called when using the `CustomSplashScreen` class in debug mode. That is because the `CustomSplashScreen` class is not actually displayed in debug mode. Instead, the system displays the default splash screen.

However, if you use the `setOnExitAnimationListener()` method, the listener will still be called when the *default* splash screen is dismissed. That is because the listener is attached to the [`SplashScreen` interface](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/splashscreen/SplashScreen), which is implemented by both the `CustomSplashScreen` class and the default splash screen.

So, even though the `setOnExitAnimationListener()` method is not called when using the `CustomSplashScreen` class in debug mode, it will still be called when the default splash screen is dismissed. That means that you can use the listener to start your app's main activity, even in debug mode.

For instance, this would use the `setOnExitAnimationListener()` method to start your app's main activity in debug mode:

```
val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()

splashScreen.setOnExitAnimationListener {
  // Start your app's main activity here.
  startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining, this is a good and detailed answer, I tried testing again on api 31, 32, the issue i was presenting seems to be fixed, however it isn't perfect like you mentioned. Seems like the logo of the splash screen is not shown anymore, I did read about issues about this too. But now like 1 out of 10 times for api 31, 32, when i normally launch the app from the launcher icon, it seems stuck on a black screen.  Maybe it's an emulator thing? cause i'm testing on real devices. I'm not sure.

Comment: Non-consistent bugs... they are the worst :( Are you using the latest version of the Android SDK?

Comment: Yea.. they're hard to debug. Yes I am